# Gson HashMap<String, List<String>> to serialize and deserialize getting error

Tags: java, android, gson

I want to store some data in string format and again retrive object from that string using gson in android.

My storing function is

```
public void storeData(HashMap<String, List<String>> data) {
    String d = new Gson().toJson(data);
    storeToXYZ(d);
}
```

Getting data function

```
public HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
    String d = getFromXYZ();
    // Assume not default data present
    if(!d.equals("")) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, List<String>>>(){}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(d, type);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am getting error at this line in getData() function

```
return new Gson().fromJson(d, type);
```

**Stacktrace**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `HashMap` to `Map`:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>(){}.getType();
```

---

#### Details:

From [LinkedTreeMap.java](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java#L38):

```
LinkedTreeMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V>
```

The `AbstractMap` inherits from `Map` interface and not from `HashMap`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do I have in my project:

```
1) private HashMap<String, File> imagesMap;<br>
2) sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(IMAGES_MAP_KEY, new Gson().toJson(imagesMap)).apply();<br>
3) imagesMap = new Gson().fromJson(imagesMapString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, File>>(){}.getType());
```

It works well.

BTW, I use

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

in dependencies.

Please check gson version, also please ensure, that you transfer exactly HashMap into `storeData()`.

**Okay, let's try another way:**

I created new project, added gson in dependencies. And here is code of MainActivity:

```
package com.example.eugenegoltsev.hashmaptest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> data;
    private String jsonString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initData();
        storeData(data);
        HashMap<String, List<String>> data2 = getData();
    }

    private void initData() {
        data = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("l1 one");
        list1.add("l1 two");
        list1.add("l1 three");

        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add("l2 one");
        list2.add("l2 two");
        list2.add("l2 three");

        data.put("First", list1);
        data.put("Second", list2);
    }

    public void storeData(HashMap<String, List<String>> data) {
        jsonString = new Gson().toJson(data);
    }

    public HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, List<String>>>(){}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
    }
}
```

`getData()` works well, just like it should.
So your problem is somewhere in other place.

You can create test HashMap, like in my code and test with it.

Comment: `storeData(String s)` only store string and nothing to do with that. I am not saving any `File` list. It's simple `List<String>`. If I am using another class or something in `HashMap` it works fine. But not in this case.